# How to find a linear extension of a poset

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, order-theory

> Give linear extensions of the three posets in the image. This is the image of the posets:

[image: This is the image of the posets]

I am unsure how to began doing linear extensions on this so if someone could please explain linear extensions with an example of a poset.

Comment: In these posets, think of  the elements as tasks, and $a<b$ means task $a$ must be done first (so in your Hasse diagram you have to do lower tasks before higher ones.) Just give an example of an order in which you can do the tasks - there will be lots of solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Given your finite poset $P$, it is clear that the first element in your linear extension must be a minimal element (else you'll not have a linear extension).  Moreover, if you picked a partial linear extension -- elements $a_1, \dots, a_k \in P$ with the property that $a_i < a_j$ in $P$ implies $i < j$ (for $1 \leq i, j \leq k$), then the next element $a_{k+1}$ in your linear extension must be a minimal element of $P \setminus \{a_1, \dots, a_k\}$.

Conversely, if you follow that recursive procedure, you'll always generate a linear extension of $P$ (exercise!).  Thus, to find linear extensions of your given posets, proceed one element at a time, always picking a minimal element of the poset of the remaining not-yet-chosen elements.