# What exactly is a linear extension ( in intuitive terms)?

Tags: combinatorics, order-theory

**Definitions**

1. $X=\{(1,i_1),(2,i_2),...,(n,i_n)\}$. Here $i_1,i_2,...,i_n$ is permutation $\sigma $ of $\{1,2,...,n\}.$
2. $R$ is a relation defined as follows $$(k,i_k)R(l,i_l)\iff k\leq l\text{ and }i_k\leq i_l.$$
3. The dimension of the poset $(X,R)$ is the smallest number of linear extensions whose intersection is $(X,R)$.

**Problem:** Prove that the dimension of the partial order set $(X,R)$ is $2$, provided that $i_1,i_2,..,i_n$ is not the identity permutation $1,2,...,n$.

**My Attempt:**
 It is easy to see that the dimension of $(X,R)$ is $1$ when $\sigma=1,2,3,...,n$. Now suppose that $\sigma\neq 1,2,3,...,n.$ Then we have to show that the dimension of $(X,R)$ is $2$. I am guessing that a constructive proof is required for this problem where we need to construct two different sets of linear extensions, but this seems very difficult. So if you are aware of alternative approaches then any hints or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Here is the original problem text from *Introductory Combinatorics* by Richard A. Brualdi.

[image]

Comment: Look carefully at your **definition** of $R$.

Comment: @LordShark could you please elaborate.

Comment: Isn't $2\leq 2$ and $1\leq 1$?

Comment: @WillOrrick I have posted the original problem from the textbook Introductory Combinatorics by Richard A Brualdi.

Comment: To try to answer your title question, in a partial order there may be elements that are incomparable, that is, you may not be able to say which of two elements is the greater.  In a linear order (or total order), you can always say which of two elements is the greater.  In a linear extension of a partial order, pairs of elements that were comparable in the partial order maintain their order.  Pairs that were incomparable in the partial order now have an order as well, so that it is possible to say which is the greater.  Loosely speaking, a linear extension provides a rule for breaking ties.

Comment: Hint for the question in the body: There is a natural, commonly used method for deciding which of two ordered pairs is the greater (which works for ordered $n$-tuples more generally, and even for strings of varying lengths).  Try seeing whether the order this gives is compatible with the partial order in your problem.  If so, it provides a linear extension.  You may then be able to get more than one linear extension out of the same idea.

Comment: Tad's comment to [this related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1488133/3736) provides a nice intuitive way to understand linear extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard lexicographic order, $L_1$, and colexicographic order, $L_2$, defined by
$$
\begin{aligned}
(a,b)L_1(c,d)&\Longleftrightarrow a<c\text{ or } (a=c\text{ and }b\le d),\\
(a,b)L_2(c,d)&\Longleftrightarrow b<d\text{ or } (b=d\text{ and }a\le c),
\end{aligned}
$$
are linear orders.  When applied to your set $X$, these reduce to
$$
\begin{aligned}
(a,b)L_1(c,d)&\Longleftrightarrow a\le c,\\
(a,b)L_2(c,d)&\Longleftrightarrow b\le d,
\end{aligned}
$$
since the cases $a=c$ and $b=d$ only arise when $(a,b)=(c,d)$.  You can check that both are linear extensions of $R$, that is, that $(a,b)R(c,d)\Longrightarrow (a,b)L_1(c,d)$ and $(a,b)R(c,d)\Longrightarrow (a,b)L_2(c,d)$.  You can also check that the intersection of $L_1$ and $L_2$ is $R$.

Comment: How can it be inferred that the dimension is 2?

Comment: Since the intersection of $L_1$ and $L_2$ is $R$, the dimension can't be more than $2$.  But the dimension can't be $1$ unless the permutation is the identity permutation, because any non-identity permutation will contain at least one pair such that $i_j>i_k$ but $j<k$, with the result that $(j,i_j)L_1(k,i_k)$ and $(k,i_k)L_2(j,i_j)$.  To see that there must be such a pair $j$, $k$, let $j$ be the smallest number such that $j\ne i_j$ and let $k$ be such that $i_k=j$.